# Allow user to select only 3 items in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Basically I want user to select only 3 items from a list in recyclerview

My adapter class holder onclicklistener code:

```
holder.addproduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        ld.setSelected(!ld.isSelected());

        if (ld.isSelected()) {
            holder.addproduct.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_checked));
        } else {
            holder.addproduct.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp));
        }

    }
});
```

My model class:

```
public class Product {
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

isSelected is used to get value of selected items in fragment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Declare a global variable int i = 0; in your adapter. Then increment that variable each time you select item. And when selecting an item check for if(i<=3). So if I is less then only proceed else don't. And remember to decease that i when you deselect that item.

Comment: You can also use a TextView to show selected count to user. Extra functionality.

Comment: You should add your listener in onCreateViewHolder() and use notifyItemChanged() inside listener. Because viewholders are recycled and you might end up with wrong selections.

Comment: Rather than just hold a counter as @ChaitanyaKarmarkar suggested, I would hold a List of selected items, and check its length when someone tries to select a new one.  The advantage of this over a counter is that you can quickly find the things that were selected when you need to without walking the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global varaible i.e `numOfSelectedItems`

```
holder.addproduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean newVal = !ld.isSelected();
        if(newVal && numOfSelectedItems >= 3) return;
        ld.setSelected(newVal);
  
        if (newVal)) {
           numOfSelectedItems++;
        } else {
            numOfSelectedItems--;
        }

    }
});
```